# Delphi - Using a function with a property setter

Tags: delphi, properties, setter

Delphi RIO -  have defined a class called TBizObj.  One of the properties has to do with DUNS numbers. DUNS numbers are sometimes '0' padded on the left to be exactly 9 characters long, so I have a property called SiteDUNS9 (based off of fSiteDUNS9).  The calling program sets the SiteDUNS9 property, but I don't the caller to have to worry about if the DUNS is 9 characters or not, I will handle that in getter/setter properties.

When I define my property to call this function, I get an error 'Incompatible types'.  Everything is string... no other types involved. Here is the relevant portion of code:

```
type
  TBizObj = class(TObject)   
  private
  ...
  fSiteDUNS9:  string;
  ... 

  function FixDunsLength9(DUNS:string) :string;

  published
  ...
  property SiteDUNS9:  string read fSiteDUNS9 write FixDunsLength9;  

  end; // End of the tBizObj Class;

implementation
...  
function TBizObj.FixDunsLength9(DUNS:string):string;
begin
  //  This is a setter function for the DUNS9 routine
  result := glib_LeftPad(DUNS, 9, '0');
end;
```

I have followed the examples on the Embaracadero site but still cannot determine what I am doing wrong.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Properties_(Delphi)

If I change my property definition to

```
 property SiteDUNS9:  string read fSiteDUNS9 write fSiteDUNS9;
```

then my program compiles correctly.

Comment: The setter needs to be a procedure that accepts a string parameter, and returns no value. Find an example in the documentation.

Comment: @David - I did, but did not catch that... :(  Submit as answer and I will accept.

Comment: `procedure FixDunsLength9(const DUNS: string);`, but you would do better calling the setter like `SetSiteDUNS9`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to declare a procedure for the setter method. As the [`Property Access`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi)#Property_Access) help says:

> **write** fieldOrMethod
>
> In a **write** specifier, if fieldOrMethod is a method, it must be a
>   procedure that takes a single value or **const** parameter of the same
>   type as the property (or more, if it is an array property or indexed
>   property).

In your case you can then write a setter like this:

```
type
  TBizObj = class(TObject)   
  private
    FSiteDUNS9: string;
    procedure FixDunsLength9(const DUNS: string);
  published
    property SiteDUNS9: string read FSiteDUNS9 write FixDunsLength9;
  end;

implementation

procedure TBizObj.FixDunsLength9(const DUNS: string);
begin
  if DUNS <> FSiteDUNS9 then
  begin
    DoSomeExtraStuff;
    FSiteDUNS9 := DUNS;
  end;
end;
```

But following the naming conventions I would recommend you to name your setter like `SetSiteDUNS9` and the parameter call `Value`.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a `procedure` instead of a `function` for a property setter. I would leave the existing function as-is, in case you need it for other purposes, and define a separate procedure for the setter:

```pascal
type
  TBizObj = class(TObject)
  private
    ...
    fSiteDUNS9: string;
    ...
    function FixDunsLength9(const DUNS: string): string;
    procedure SetSiteDUNS9(const Value: string);
  published
    ...
    property SiteDUNS9: string read fSiteDUNS9 write SetSiteDUNS9;
  end;
  // End of the tBizObj Class;

implementation

...

function TBizObj.FixDunsLength9(const DUNS: string): string;
begin
  Result := glib_LeftPad(DUNS, 9, '0');
end;

procedure TBizObj.SetSiteDUNS9(const Value: string);
var
  NewValue: string;
begin
  NewValue := FixDunsLength9(Value);
  if fSiteDUNS9 <> NewValue then
  begin
    fSiteDUNS9 := NewValue;
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is better as one can reuse the `FixDunsLength9` function anywhere else within the class.

Comment: Good idea.  Thank you!